# Does Tor route traffic through clients?

Tags: relays, mac, client

My friend and I were talking about Tor in class, and I had my laptop out, running `Tor` for it's SOCKS proxy to access censored websites. My teacher interjected that I should not use Tor at school because it routes other's traffic through clients so, by me using Tor, I am also routing the traffic of other Tor users.

I am not sure whether or not this is legitimate, and if I should be worried about it.

Answer (score 1):

Tor unlike some other anonymizers does not route the other's traffic through clients at this time, and there is no plan to do so as far as I know in future. You should not worry about this. Anybody, if she desire may run a relay. Relays route the traffic of all clients. Running a relay is voluntery and client are not obligated to run a relay.